# Can't install WINE on KDE neon 2.26 (Ubuntu 22.10)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine, kde-neon

I can't install WINE on KDE neon 5.26 (Ubuntu 22.10). I followed the WineHQ installation guide https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu.

I know that KDE neon comes with WINE pre-installed, but I've removed it prior to installing the new version.

The step that fails is the actual `winehq-stable` package installation. I've tried `winehq-devel` and `winehq-staging` packages, but ended up with the same results.

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) winehq-stable:amd64 < none -> 7.0.1~kinetic-1 @un puN Ib >
Broken winehq-stable:amd64 Depends on wine-stable:amd64 < none @un H > (= 7.0.1~kinetic-1)
  Considering wine-stable:amd64 0 as a solution to winehq-stable:amd64 9999
  Considering wine-stable:i386 0 as a solution to winehq-stable:amd64 9999
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.1~kinetic-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've checked if I maybe have some stray WINE packages installed, but there's nothing, except for an unfortunate kwin package that has "wine" in it's name:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep wine

libkwineffects14/jammy,now 4:5.26.3-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build21 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: Did you try installing `wine-stable` before `winehq-stable`?

Comment: No, but isn't `wine-stable` contained within `winehq-stable`? If I install `wine-stable`, won't I have to install other dependencies that would be contained by `winehq-stable` anyways?

Comment: just a note, KDE Neon is ***not*** Ubuntu 22.10.  Neon is built on Ubuntu, but they are not the same.  Neon is KDE's distro for testing.  However, Neon devs say it really shouldnt be used as a "daily driver" and to use Ubuntu instead.  It should be used to test or use the latest KDE software.

Comment: @Keltari where do they say that? I've been using KDE Neon for almost a year now as my daily driver and it's been very pleasant, excluding a few `plasmashell` restarts here and there and this issue with Wine, but generally everything else is good.

Answer (score 2):

Someone has solved this issue by installing an older version of `libpoppler-glib8`: https://www.reddit.com/r/kdeneon/comments/ya6wmb/comment/itaavu8/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

---

> And then there was only one package causing an issue. You can see that Neon provides this in `amd64`:
>
> ```
> $ apt show -a libpoppler-glib8 | grep Version
> Version: 22.09.0-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build3
> Version: 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1
> Version: 22.02.0-2
> ```
>
> But doesn't provide an i386 version at all:
>
> ```
> $ apt show -a libpoppler-glib8:i386 | grep Version
> Version: 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1
> Version: 22.02.0-2
> ```
>
> So then you can install the Ubuntu version for both architectures like so:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install libpoppler-glib8:{i386,amd64}=22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1
> ```
>
> And then WINE installs just fine

After this you can install the wine package from one of the wine branches. In this case I'll pick `winehq-stable`:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```